# Imagemagick convert make thumbnail bigger than box

Tags: imagemagick, thumbnails, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to make thumbnails which would be bigger than a box. Idea is to show thumbnail and on mouse over show the correct aspect ratio.

Example

```
Box size: 100x100 (min size)

If image is 3000x2000, i need 150x100
If image is 2000x3000, i need 100x150
```

I can do the logic in code externally, but it would be preferable to use imagemagick.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a maximum output size of 150×150 pixels should do what you want:

```
convert input.jpg -resize 150x150 output.jpg
```

The geometry passed to `-resize` is the maximum size [by default](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry). The aspect ratio is preserved.

You can also specify a mininum size like this:

```
convert input.jpg -resize 100x100^ output.jpg
```